# how to destroy table and reinitialize same table with new updated data using Datatables Jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, function, datatables

I am using Datatables plugin and dynmically populating the table with the data returned from server. on different table draws the returned data has variable no of columns. On each table intilization the code is checking if there has been previous initializations and removes it before creating a new table with dynamic data, using this code:

```
 if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#contracts_forecast' ) ) {

  $('#contracts_forecast').DataTable().clear();
  $('#contracts_forecast').DataTable().destroy();
$('#contracts_forecast tbody').empty();
$('#contracts_forecast thead').empty();


}
```

On the serverside I am manually editing the data and updating the database. When the database is updated with new data , I want to refresh the table so the change is reflected in the table. In order to do that I am using an POST SUBMIT event, which is triggered after the data is submitted to server and then call the function  **getDT(filter_product_code, filter_product_name)** to update the table with new data

PROBLEM:

When the post submit event is triggered , it recalls the function  getDT(filter_product_code, filter_product_name); and change is reflected. **BUT THE NEW TABLE with UPDATED IS ADDED TO CURRENT TABLE WITHOUT THE OLD TABLE BEING DESTROYED Which leaves me with two same tables on screen**

p.s I am assuming every time  getDT() function is called it should check for if table is initialized and destroy it before creating a new one using the same

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    
      $('#filter').click(function(){
    
    
      var  filter_product_code = $('#filter_product_code').val();
      var filter_product_name = $('#filter_product_name').val();
    
    
       if(filter_product_code == '' || filter_product_name == '')
       {
     alert('Select Both filter option');
       }
    
    
    var columns = [];
    
    getDT(filter_product_code, filter_product_name);
    
    function getDT(filter_product_code, filter_product_name) {
    
      $.ajax({
    
                    serverSide: true,
                     type:'POST',
    
             url: "/XXX/_fetch.php",
    
              data:  {filter_product_code: JSON.stringify(filter_product_code),
    
    
               filter_product_name: JSON.stringify(filter_product_name)},
    
                  success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            columnNames = Object.keys(data.data[0]);
            for (var i in columnNames) {
              columns.push({data: columnNames[i], 
                        title: capitalizeFirstLetter(columnNames[i])});
                                           
    
            }
    
    
    
      if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#contracts_forecast' ) ) {
    
      $('#contracts_forecast').DataTable().clear();
      $('#contracts_forecast').DataTable().destroy();
    $('#contracts_forecast tbody').empty();
    $('#contracts_forecast thead').empty();
    
    
    }
     
        table = $('#contracts_forecast').DataTable({
              data: data.data,
                columns: columns,
              
                dom: "Bfrtip",
                select: true,
            buttons: [
                { extend: "create", editor: editor },
                { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
                { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
            ],
             "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": false
                },
                 { className: "tablecolumns", targets: "_all" },
                ]
            } );
    
       $('#contracts_forecast').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
    
          editor.inline( this );
    
        } );
    
     }
      
        });
 editor.on( 'postSubmit', function (  e, json, data, action, xhr  ) {

 getDT(filter_product_code, filter_product_name);

      });
    }
    
      });
    
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a mistake by declaring the column variable outside function. Each time the function was called it was adding to already existing columns. So just needed to define column variable inside function.

```
getDT(filter_product_code, filter_product_name);

function getDT(filter_product_code, filter_product_name) {

    var columns = [];


  $.ajax({

                serverSide: true,
                // paging: true,
                // retrieve:true,
                                         type:'POST',
```